# Alternative to the ProtoBuff encoding for REST?

Tags: java, rest, protocol-buffers

I'm looping through the Java POJO (fetching data from the database) and then using protostuff library to covert it into byte[] and again encoding it into ProtoBuff classes so that I can send it as a content-type →application/x-protobuf

My biggest concern is in the folloiwing line, where I need to encode for each row:

```
for (InstrumentHistory instrumentHistory : instrumentHistoryRepository.getAllInstrumentHistorys()) {
        Schema<InstrumentHistory> schema = RuntimeSchema.getSchema(InstrumentHistory.class);
        LinkedBuffer buffer = LinkedBuffer.allocate(LinkedBuffer.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
        final byte[] protostuff;
        try {
            protostuff = ProtostuffIOUtil.toByteArray(instrumentHistory, schema, buffer);
            instrumentHistoryProtos.add(InstrumentHistoryProto.InstrumentHistory.parseFrom(protostuff));
        } finally {
            buffer.clear();
        }
    }
    return InstrumentHistoryProto.InstrumentHistorys.newBuilder().addAllInstrumentHistory(instrumentHistoryProtos).build();
```

Is there any workaround or simple way to do this?

Comment: OK. Maybe I'm missing something. But it looks like you take your object, convert it to a byte array, then convert it *back* into an object, then add it to another object. Why would you do that? Admittedly I've never used "protostuff"  and have just used the regular protobuf-java libraries, so maybe it's a weirdness from that...

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas InstrumentHistory is Java POJO class and InstrumentHistoryProto is generated from ProtoBuff compiler. I'm getting the data from JDBC and needs to send it in protobuff message instead of JSON. How do you send protobuff over http/REST?